# When to change the Wiper blades?

Tags: windshield-wipers

My car windshield wiper has started making noise every time I turn them on. I have tried to clean my window with Rain-x.  After cleaning, it doesn't make any sound but a day or two later it start making sound again.

Is this the time I should change my wiper blade? It's a used car so I have no idea how old are they.

How to verify if I really need a new wiper blade?

Comment: Perhaps there is wax on the windscreen, which can come from carwash brushes even if you didn't select a "wax" program. That horrible stuff - completely unnecessary with modern paint finishes - makes the wipers graunch and the window dangerously opaque when it is smeared by the wipers in the rain. IMO it can only be removed with T-cut. Similarly, another ill-advised practice of the motor trade is to spray the inside with furniture polish, which not only makes everything slimy, but makes the doors squeak if it gets on the rubber edge seals.

Comment: Replace every 6-12 months.

Answer (score 2):

The big question you need to ask yourself when considering the wipers is ... *Do they work?* Are they cleaning the windshield without streaking? Are they removing the water as expected? If not, replace them. If the rubber of the wiper is splitting or tearing off the frame, replace them. IOW, if you're not happy with them, replace them. There is no set "this is the time".

As far as noise goes, when you clean your windshield, clean your wipers at the same time. This will help them continue to work. The easiest way I have found to do this is at the gas station, if you clean your windshield with what is provided there, turn it so the washer side (sponge) is up, placing it under the wiper and wipe it the entire length. You'll usually see a swipe of black on the squeegee sponge. Once cleaned, you'll find they will provide a much improved swipe. There are other ways to clean it as well, like cutting an apple in half and swiping it along the wiper blade to clean it. Some have even suggested a potato. It will take the "junk" off of the blade and allow it to work again.

Comment: I cleaned the wipre blade everytime I clean window.  And yeah.. it's cleaning snow and rain without much issue. it's just this terrible noice.. :) is there a way I can fix this ?

Comment: The potato is best used to wipe the screen - the starch allows the rain to "roll" off the screen as droplets when driving along.

Comment: @GaurangShah - Then you aren't completely cleaning it or you need to replace them.